# Angular Guard Invalidation

Tags: angular, typescript, guard, auth-guard

I would like my auth guard to allow/restrict access based on an observable that periodically triggers a boolean. My idea was:

```js
auth$ = interval(5000).pipe(map((n) => n % 2 === 0));

canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.auth$;
}
```

It works when the triggers goes from `false` to `true`, but not the opposite, looks like the guard is not active anymore then.

Answer (score 0):

A guard is triggered once on every navigation start.

Once angular got the first emit from a guard it unsubscribes and uses the emitted value to allow / forbid the routing.

It means - you can't emit values in guard periodically to change the originally emitted value.

What you're trying to achieve can be implemented the next way:

```js
import {Injectable, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate} from '@angular/router';
import {interval, Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {map, takeUntil, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, OnDestroy {
    protected readonly auth$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
    protected readonly destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

    constructor(
    ) {
        interval(5000).pipe(
            map(n => n % 2 === 0),
            tap(value => this.auth$.next(value)),
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        ).subscribe();
    }

    public canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.auth$;
    }

    // not sure if this part works for guards
    // but would be nice to unsubscribe once you don't need this guard
    // anymore
    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Angular does not call ngOnDestroy in AuthGuards. Do you have any solutions for it?

Comment: it depends how you configured your application to use guards, services (guards) do support `OnDestroy`: https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy

Comment: or you can use another service which would fetch data periodically and a component would be responsible to start and stop fetching, where the guard would simply rely on the current value of the service, in this case, the guard doesn't need observables at all.